# emersion/go-imap - imap.FetchRFC822: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go, imap, email-attachments

I am trying to fetch all E-Mails from the Server with the following source Code (this function is called in the main module):

```
package internal

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "github.com/emersion/go-imap"
    "github.com/emersion/go-imap/client"
    "github.com/emersion/go-message"
)

func FetchEMail(server string, username string, password string) error {
    //Connect to Server
    log.Println("Connecting to server...")

    c, err := client.DialTLS(server, nil)
    log.Println("Connected to " + server)
    defer c.Logout()

    //check if connection successful
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("In connection Error")
        return err
    }

    //err = nil

    //Login
    log.Println("Logging in...")
    err = c.Login(username, password)
    log.Println("Logged in as " + username)

    //check if login successful
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("In login Error")
        return err
    }

    //Select INBOX
    log.Println("Selecting INBOX...")
    mbox, err := c.Select("INBOX", false)
    log.Println("Selected INBOX")

    //check if select successful
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    //Fetch all messages
    log.Println("Fetching all messages...")
    seqset := new(imap.SeqSet)
    seqset.AddRange(1, mbox.Messages)
    items := []imap.FetchItem{imap.FetchRFC822}
    messages := make(chan *imap.Message, 10)
    done := make(chan error, 1)
    go func() {
        done <- c.Fetch(seqset, items, messages)
    }()

    //check if fetch successful
    if err := <-done; err != nil {
        log.Println("In fetch Error")
        return err
    }

    log.Println("Run Successful - Terminating...")
    return nil
}
```

This results into the following error:

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
> [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x5ee505]
>
> goroutine 1 [running]:

I already have tried imap.FetchEvelope() which works, but for some reason imap.FetchRFC822 does not work.

My main goal is to export all E-Mail attachments (.gz, .zip, ...) from all E-Mails, that is why I need the whole E-Mail, not only the Envelope.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue was in this line `items := []imap.FetchItem{imap.FetchRFC822}`.
First, let's clarify what the `FetchItem` type is. This represents the different parts of an email that can be fetched (envelope, body, UID, flags, and so on).
Then, let's talk about the `Fetch` method. It expects a slice of `imap.FetchItem` passed in. It retrieves from the emails all of the parts specified by the slice.
So what fixes your issue is replacing this line with `items := []imap.FetchItem{imap.FetchRFC822, imap.FetchEnvelope}`.
I fixed and tested your program as you can see from the code snippet below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/emersion/go-imap"
    "github.com/emersion/go-imap/client"
)

func FetchEMail(server string, username string, password string) error {
    // Connect to Server
    log.Println("Connecting to server...")

    c, err := client.Dial(server)
    log.Println("Connected to " + server)
    defer c.Logout()

    // check if connection successful
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("In connection Error")
        return err
    }

    // Login
    log.Println("Logging in...")
    err = c.Login(username, password)
    log.Println("Logged in as " + username)

    // check if login successful
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("In login Error")
        return err
    }

    // Select INBOX
    log.Println("Selecting INBOX...")
    mbox, err := c.Select("INBOX", false)
    log.Println("Selected INBOX")

    // check if select successful
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Fetch all messages
    log.Println("Fetching all messages...")
    seqset := new(imap.SeqSet)
    seqset.AddRange(1, mbox.Messages)
    items := []imap.FetchItem{imap.FetchRFC822, imap.FetchEnvelope}
    messages := make(chan *imap.Message, 10)
    done := make(chan error, 1)
    go func() {
        done <- c.Fetch(seqset, items, messages)
    }()

    for msg := range messages {
        fmt.Printf("suject: %v\n", msg.Envelope.Subject)
    }

    // check if fetch successful
    if err := <-done; err != nil {
        log.Println("In fetch Error")
        return err
    }

    log.Println("Run Successful - Terminating...")
    return nil
}

func main() {
    err := FetchEMail("xxxxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Near the end, I added a `for` to print the subject of the retrieved emails. Here, you can replace the code with your own logic. The `nil pointer dereference` error disappears.
Let me know if this solves your issue!